# while using import statement which file will be loaded the typescript main file or javascript file?

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, node-modules

[image]When we import a package in Node, some of the packages might have a main file with typescript  file and java script file .I have used the import syntax and when I found the reference where my package takes it's main file .It is a typescript file .. So If a package is being imported whether it would be the js file is loaded or ts file is loaded. **I have used this code in a javascript file not a typescript file**

For some reference I have added a image **above** that shows the case:

1. marking 1 - the underline with green marker represents, main file is loaded when hovered above the import package of import dotenv from 'dotenv';
2. marking 2- the box represented by green color,here it shows the file which imported which is the typescript as it has the interface keyword.